# Nao-Robot Qi Chat installation

Tags: python, nao-robot

I am working with naoqi robot and have created QiChat program. I have installed the program to naoqi as well. But I want him to talk using those words without any triggered sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger the sentences with u:(e:onStart), the robot will speak them right away.
For instance :

```
u:(e:onStart)
^rand["Hello" "Hi" "Good morning"]
```